# How to make migrations for a reusable Django app?

Tags: python, django, migration

I am making a reusable Django app without a project. This is the directory structure:

```
/
/myapp/
/myapp/models.py
/myapp/migrations/
/myapp/migrations/__init__.py
```

When I run `django-admin makemigrations` I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Obviously, this is because I don't have a settings module configured, because this is a reusable app. However, I would still like to ship migrations with my app. How can I make them?

Comment: You create and test the migration in an app, then ship is alone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to have project, all you need is settings file and script, that runs migrations creation.
Settings must contain folowing (minimum):

```
# test_settings.py

DEBUG = True

SECRET_KEY = 'fake-key'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'your_app'
]
```

And the script, that makes migrations should look like this:

```
# make_migrations.py

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "test_settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    args = sys.argv + ["makemigrations", "your_app"]
    execute_from_command_line(args)
```

and you should run it by `python make_migrations.py`. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: That was helpful. Worked for me. You don't need though a migrations script @Compadre, `django-admin makemigrations` is sufficient (with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set properly in env variable)

Answer (score 11):

You need a functional Django project (with your app installed in it) to make migrations.

A common way to do this is to have a "test" project which contains the bare necessities of a Django project, that you can run to make migrations etc. The migrations will be created in the right place inside your app directory so you can still have proper version control etc within your own reusable app.

The migrations created in this way will be self-contained (assuming your models don't depend on models from other apps) and can be shipped as part of your packaged, reusable app.

Many of the larger Django-based projects actually ship a test project as part of their code, so that developers can quickly get it running in order to test apps and make migrations etc.

Comment: I made a test project, but I am not able create migrations for my reusable app, which is in the outside directory of the test app.

Comment: I am also struggling with this.  I can get the "make_migrations.py" script below to work, but the answer above doesn't work because of the directory placement.

Comment: Actually, regarding the directory placement, I was able to get this working by including the reusable app into the test project's virtual environment using something like `pip install ..` or `pipenv install -e ..`.

Answer (score 5):

Create `your_app/migrations_settings.py` file:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'fake-key'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'your_app'
]
```

then

```sh
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yourapp.migrations_settings
django-admin makemigrations yourapp
```

Comment: Can you share the folder structure of your package? Because I created one and tried this with `test_settings.py` (with same content as above), both inside and outside of the main app folder. And it give me the same error `ModuleNotFoundError` while accessing settings module

Comment: @SadanArshad Does your main app folder (say `yourapp`) contains `__init__` file so it is considered a package? If so then `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yourapp.test_settings` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Real Python has a tutorial on writting a reusable Django App.

The chapter [Bootstrapping Django Outside of a Project](https://realpython.com/installable-django-app/#bootstrapping-django-outside-of-a-project) has a very interesting example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# boot_django.py

"""
This file sets up and configures Django. It's used by scripts that need to
execute as if running in a Django server.
"""

import os

import django
from django.conf import settings


BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "your_app"))


def boot_django():

    settings.configure(
        BASE_DIR=BASE_DIR,
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            "default":{
                "ENGINE":"django.db.backends.sqlite3",
                "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
            }
        },
        INSTALLED_APPS=(
            "django.contrib.auth",
            "django.contrib.contenttypes",
            "your_app",
        ),
        TIME_ZONE="UTC",
        USE_TZ=True,
    )

    django.setup()
```

And then:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# makemigrations.py

from django.core.management import call_command
from boot_django import boot_django

boot_django()
call_command("makemigrations", "your_app")
```