# How to ship migrations in a Django reusable app?

Tags: django, database, web-applications, migration

I can create migrations for my reusable application from a minimal test project, but that would install the migrations in -

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_app-0.1-py3.5.egg/django_app/migrations/0001_initial.py
```

I wanna ship the migrations with the reusable app, Do I just copy the file or is there any other method?

Comment: Just copy your whole app directory and migrate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make migrations for a reusable Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528286/how-to-make-migrations-for-a-reusable-django-app)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1) Add the test project to your reusable app's repo for the purposes of creating migrations and perhaps as a usage example, as [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) does.

2) Keep your test project as a separate repo, and symlink the reusable app repo into the test project's directory as a dependency. Create migrations using the test project and the migration files will be created in your reusable app's repo directory, ready to be committed.

Keen to hear what other people are doing!