# Creating migrations for a reusable Django app

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-apps

I am writing a reusable Django app and having problems creating migrations.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528286/how-to-make-migrations-for-a-reusable-django-app), and I'm still confused.  I have the following sort of directory structure:

```
django-mycleverapp/
django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/
django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/__init__.py
django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/apps.py
django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/models.py
django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/urls.py
django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/views.py
django-mycleverapp/example/
django-mycleverapp/example/manage.py
django-mycleverapp/example/example/
django-mycleverapp/example/example/__init__.py
django-mycleverapp/example/example/settings.py
django-mycleverapp/example/example/urls.py
django-mycleverapp/setup.py
```

As you can see, the directory "django_mycleverapp" contains my reusable app and the directory "example" contains a test project.

I include the models of "django_mycleverapp" in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of the settings for "example".

However, running `python ~/example/manage.py makemigrations django_mycleverapp` doesn't build any migrations.

Any suggestions?

How am I meant to have a test project that will build migrations in "/django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/migrations"?

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be in the directory of your project. Your directory hierarchy should look like this.

```
django-mycleverapp/
django-mycleverapp/example/
django-mycleverapp/example/django_mycleverapp/
django-mycleverapp/example/django_mycleverapp/__init__.py
django-mycleverapp/example/django_mycleverapp/apps.py
django-mycleverapp/example/django_mycleverapp/models.py
django-mycleverapp/example/django_mycleverapp/urls.py
django-mycleverapp/example/django_mycleverapp/views.py
django-mycleverapp/example/manage.py
django-mycleverapp/example/example/
django-mycleverapp/example/example/__init__.py
django-mycleverapp/example/example/settings.py
django-mycleverapp/example/example/urls.py
django-mycleverapp/example/setup.py
```

---

If you do not want your app to be part of your "example" project, but rather want it to be separated and used by your project "example", you'll have to install it in your project using `pip` (this requires to have a `setup.py` at the root of your app).

For instance if you have published your app on a git repository "https://gitlab.com/myuser/myproject.git", you can add to our `requirements.txt`:

```
git+https://gitlab.com/myuser/myproject.git@v1.0#egg=myapp_name
```

If you don't have your app published on a git repository yet, you can add the absolute path to your app to you `requirements.txt`:

```
/path/to/django-mycleverapp/django_mycleverapp/
```

Don't forget to work in a virtualenv when you use `pip`.

Comment: That is answering how to make migrations generally. Should there be always an `example` project that have settings properly set and can be used to generate migrations?